# C++ function pointers in derived classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, function-pointers

Here is my problem:

I have a base class containing a method that "registers" this class' function to a certain string ID using function pointer. I have managed to get it working, but I need derived classes to be able to use this mechanism as well. The compiler forced me to specify the function pointers using the class name that containes the called function (notation `BaseClass::*`). That will obviously not work when I create a derived class.

Here is simplified code that I currently have in the base class (I have it split between .hh and .cc files - that's why is the implementation separeted):

```
class BaseClass{
    public:
       BaseClass();
    private:
       std::map<std::string, void (BaseClass::*)( argType* )> actionMap;

       void registerAction( void (BaseClass::*)( argType* ), std::string actionID );
}

BaseClass::BaseClass(){
    std::string actionID = "myAction";
    void (BaseClass::*fcnPointer)(argType*);
    fcnPointer = &BaseClass::sendEthernetFrame;

    registerAction( fcnPointer, actionID );
}

void BaseClass::registerAction( void (BaseClass::*actionHandler)( argType* ), std::string actionID ){
    actionMap.insert ( std::pair<std::string,void (BaseClass::*)(argType*)>(actionID ,actionHandler) );
}
```

What I need is, to be somehow able to store and address different class' function pointers in one list and be able to all call them at the highest level of the inheritance chain (each derived class may add its own functions that will need to be registered).

I find it very odd, that I can't store different class' function pointers as one type, since the pointers are just addresses in the end, aren't they?

Comment: I don't think that this can be done without using some kind of type erasure like `std::function`.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to use non-static class methods for this.  C++ has no notion of "closures", which would allow a derived method pointer to be assigned to, and called from, a base class method pointer.  You will have to use a different design.  For instance, you could store a list of `BaseClass` object pointers instead (since you need them anyway to call a non-static class method), and when needed you can then call a `virtual` method on those objects and have each derived class override that method as needed.

Comment: Well, the problem is, that I don't know in advance what methods will there be, in the derived classes. The idea is, that user could create a derived class and add a function to it. Then, by registering it, a function coded in the very base class could take this newly defined function into account (based on the stringID). Well I guess I will have to try to come up with another design.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need a collection of `BaseClass`, you could use template instead, and pass the derived type into the template.

```
template <typename DERIVED>
class BaseClass {
    std::map<std::string, void (DERIVED::*)( argType* )> actionMap;
protected:
    void registerAction(
        void (DERIVED::*)( argType* ), std::string actionID);
    //...
};

class Derived : public BaseClass<Derived> {
    //...
    Derived () {
        registerAction(&sendEthernetFrame, "myAction");
    }
};
```